# discord py constantly update status for bot

Tags: discord.py

Ok, So i want it to update status text whenever a number changes or a update happens in the db.
Cause i want to show how many people are online, i got a PHP function for it that i call with requests in python, but how would i make it so if its changed since last time it updates the status from 1 online to 2 online for example?

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   while True: 
    response = json.loads(requests.get(weburl + f"/api/index.php?totalonline").text)
    string = "Currently " + str(response["message"]) + " online"
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=string))
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `while` loop for that. Instead use `tasks`. Define a task that will repeat itself every one second and start it in `on_ready` event.

Example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    if not loop.is_running():
        loop.start()


@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def loop():
    print("I'm running!")
    # your repetitive task


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Don't start tasks inside `on_ready`, it fires multiple times inside a running bot, start it inside a cog __init__ or just the global scope and wait until ready to execute it

Comment: Edited so it will start only once

Comment: Yes but this will do it every second and discord ratelimits you if you change status too often. So i need it to only change if the number from the response has updated.

Comment: So check if the response updated with `if` statement and if it didn't don't update status